# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 4 episode 12?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Can someone please help me find the song used in the newest episode (12) of season 4. It starts at the 15:50 mark in, when Mirio and Deku finally realize what happened to Nighteye. I can't seem to find it on any of the soundtrack lists for the season. I love the music of it and would love to know what song it is.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxSVeuMTMfk

It is an edited version of AFO's theme.
You can't get anything but the complete version, sadly :c
I hope this helps anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It's *Polaris* by BLUE ENCOUNT, which is also used as the opening song for the 4th season of *My Hero Academia*.